# Center align entire webpage

Tags: html, css, containers, center

I'm having trouble center aligning my entire webpage template, I've created a basic mock up of what I want my pages to look like but cannot seem to center it.

The code is as follows

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<link href="../css/website_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #000;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="header">

  <div id="nav">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Home | About Us | Events | Gallery | More...
    </p>
  </div> 
  <div id="logotop"><img src="../Images/images/Logotop.png" width="200" height="100"></div>  
</div>

<div id="middletop">

    <div id="logobottom"><img src="../Images/images/Logobottom.png" width="200" height="100"></div>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>Page Name</p></div>

<div id="middle">
    <div id="twitter">
      <p>This is where the Twitter link will go      </p>
    </div>
    <div id="facebook">
      <p>This is where the FB link will go      </p>
    </div>
    </div>

<div id="middlebottom">

    <div id="sectionone">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>Section one text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sectiontwo">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>Section two text</p>
  </div>
  </div>
<div id="bottom">


<div id="sectionthree">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>Section one text</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sectionfour">
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
      <p>Section two text</p>
  </div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
#header {
    height: 100px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #000;
}
#logotop {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 200px;
}

#nav {
    float: right;
    height: 100px;
    width: 800px;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
#middletop {
    height: 400px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 36px;
    /* [disabled]margin-top: 3px; */
}
#logobottom {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 200px;
}
#middle {
    height: 50px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-image: url(../Images/images/images/backgrounds_02.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #000;
}
#facebook {
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 550px;
}
#twitter {
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    height: 50px;
    width: 550px;
}
#middlebottom {
    font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    height: 225px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-image: url(../Images/images/images/backgrounds_03.png);
}
#sectionone {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    float: left;
    height: 225px;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}
#sectiontwo {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 225px;
    width: 600px;
    float: right;
}
#bottom {
    height: 225px;
    width: 1200px;
    background-image: url(../Images/images/images/ParanormalWebsiteTempV2_04.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#sectionthree {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    height: 225px;
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
}
#sectionfour {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    height: 225px;
    width: 600px;
}
#container {
    height: 1050px;
    width: 1200px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me :)

Comment: Full code dumps aren't really that useful - if you can narrow it down to specifics it's easier for us, so you'll get your answer quicker.

Comment: #container {height: 1050px;
 width: 1200px; margin:0 auto; text-align:left;} body { text-align:center}

Comment: Here is a fiddle of the above code http://jsfiddle.net/FsYEw/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
#container {
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FsYEw/

Answer (score 1):

Set equal side margins on the outer element:

```
#container {margin: 0 auto;}
```